# SQL server version differences

Tags: sql-server

My SQL server version is as below

[image: SQL Server version]

but When i check in summary.txt at this path below [image]

The product version is different which 13.2.5698 as below

[image]

Can anyone advise me why it's different in summary.txt files

Comment: yes, reboot pending but what is the product version 13.2.5698? i can't find anything related to product version 13.2.5698 in SQL server 2016

Comment: build number: 13.0.5698.0 is CU12. Please reboot and double-check. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4536648/cumulative-update-12-for-sql-server-2016-sp2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that, in the summary.txt log file, that second build number is used to indicate the service pack level.

13.**0**.5698.0 is SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU12.  Summary.txt replaces that bolded **0** with a **2** to indicate it's SP2.

I double checked this on a few of my instances of SQL Server, and it seems to hold true for SQL Server 2016 and 2014 consistently.  For instance, I have a SQL Server 2014 SP2 GDR instance installed locally, and Summary.txt shows the patch level as 12.**2**.5223.6, even though the real build number (per `@@VERSION`) is 12.**0**.5223.6.

The details of what is in Summary.txt aren't documented per se, so it's probably best to rely on `SELECT @@VERSION` rather than the contents of that file.